# How to find limits of this volume integration?

Tags: definite-integrals

The question is

> If $\vec { F } = x \hat { i } + y \hat { j } + z \hat { k }$ then find the value of $\int \int _ { S } \vec { F } \cdot \hat { n } d s$ where $S$ is the sphere  $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \vert x ^ { 2 } + y ^ { 2 } + z ^ { 2 } = 4\}$.

Here if I'll calculate the answer using gauss divergence theorem, then I have to find the volume integral of the function, but how will I take the limits of the integration. Can someone help please? 
Thank you.

Comment: What about  $$0\le \rho\le2\;,\;\;0\le\theta\le2\pi\;,\;\;0\le\phi\le\pi\;?$$  These is the parametrization of the given sphere in spherical coordinates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have ${\bf F}({\bf x}):={\bf x}$, and on the sphere $S$ of radius $2$ you have ${\bf n}({\bf x})={1\over2}{\bf x}$. Furthermore $$\int_S{\rm d}\omega=4\cdot4\pi\ .$$ It follows that
$$\int_S{\bf F}({\bf x})\cdot{\bf n}({\bf x})\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_S{\bf x}\cdot{1\over2}{\bf x}\>{\rm d}\omega=2\cdot16\pi=32\pi\ .$$

Comment: sir,can you provide some method in which one can derive the limits directly from the given equation of the surface without knowing the geometry of the surface or plotting a graph?